# Sortable("cancel") being ignored in receive callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

```
$('.batch_listing').sortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    forceHelperSize: true,
    placeholder: 'photo_ghost',
    helper: 'clone',
    receive: function(event, ui) 
    { 
        if(!is_in_batch(ui.item.children("a").children("img").attr("data-photo-id"))) 
        { 
            add_to_batch_dispatch(ui.item.children("a").children("img").attr("data-photo-id"));
        } else { 
            //Remove from batch
            $(this).sortable("cancel");
            alert("shouldn't be added");
        }
    },
    sort: function(event, ui) {
        if(placing == false) 
        {
            $(".destory_drop").fadeIn();
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        if(removing == false)
        {
            $(".destory_drop").fadeOut();
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

I have a series of draggables that are connected to this sortable.

```
$("#photo_browser li").draggable({
    snap: false,
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.5,
    connectToSortable: "ul.batch_listing",
    start: function(e, ui){
        placing = true;
    }, 
    stop: function(e, ui){
        placing = false;
    }
});
```

The code itself is working correctly, is_in_batch and add_to_batch_dispatch, which just logs the ID from the item and checks to see if it already exists in the sortable. HOWEVER, whenever I call `$(this).sortable("cancel")`, the draggable is still dropped into the sortable (and the test alert in the code is called).

Originally, this did work before somewhere along the line it stopped; I've been spending hours trying to find out why, so some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`$(this).sortable("cancel");`

try

```
return false;
```